# Morris bar is not working with dynamic values using json

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am using morris bar getting dynamic values from json

This is the morris js code

```
$(function() { 
  var str='';
  jQuery.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "today_attendance.php",
  success: function(data)
   {
    //alert(data);
    //console.log(data);
    //uploaddata(data);
    str=data;
   }
});

Morris.Bar({
    element: 'morris-bar',
    data: str,

    //data: 
    // [{x:'B1',y:14,z:0},{x:'B2',y:27,z:5},{x:'B3',y:38,z:100}, 
    // {x:'B4',y:77,z:73},{x:'B5',y:71,z:71},{x:'B6',y:0,z:57}, 
    // {x:'B7',y:0,z:89},{x:'B8',y:71,z:59},{x:'B9',y:0,z:16}, 
    // {x:'B10',y:5,z:63},{x:'B11',y:0,z:0}],
    xkey: 'x',
    ykeys: ['y', 'z'],
    labels: ['A', 'B']
});
});
```

Here is the php code where ajax calling a page

```
<?php
  require_once("../../assets/db_connect.php");

  //$Today = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
     $Today = '2018-08-17 00:00:00';
  //Get Current Session
     $Res_Sess = mysql_query("SELECT sessionid from tbl_session where status=1 ORDER BY sessionid desc limit 1");
     $Row_Sess = mysql_fetch_array($Res_Sess); $Session = $Row_Sess[0];
     $Res_Bat = mysql_query("SELECT batchid,batchname,code FROM tbl_batch where status=1 and batchid!=12 ORDER BY batchid asc");
     $i=1; $Str = array();
     while($Row_Bat = mysql_fetch_array($Res_Bat)){
        $Batch = $Row_Bat['batchid'];  $Bat_Code = $Row_Bat['code'];
       //Get Modules
       $Res_Mod = mysql_query("SELECT distinct module_id from tbl_attendance where batchid = '$Batch' and sessionid = '$Session' LIMIT 2"); 
        $index =1; $Attendance='';
     if(mysql_num_rows($Res_Mod)>0){
        While($Row_Mod = mysql_fetch_array($Res_Mod)){
        $Mod_ID = $Row_Mod[0];
        //Get Total 
         $qatt1 = mysql_query("select count(id) from tbl_attendance where module_id = '$Mod_ID' and batchid = '$Batch' and sessionid = '$Session' and date ='$Today'");
        $qatt2 = mysql_query("select count(id) from tbl_attendance where module_id = '$Mod_ID' and batchid = '$Batch' and sessionid = '$Session' and attend = 1 and date ='$Today'");
        $qatt3 = mysql_query("select count(id) from tbl_attendance where module_id = '$Mod_ID' and batchid = '$Batch' and sessionid = '$Session' and attend = 0 and date ='$Today'");
        $qatt4 = mysql_query("select count(id) from tbl_attendance where module_id = '$Mod_ID' and batchid = '$Batch' and sessionid = '$Session' and attend = 2 and date ='$Today'");
        $Row_T = mysql_fetch_array($qatt1);
        $totalatt = $Row_T[0];
        $Row_P = mysql_fetch_array($qatt2); $tpresent = $Row_P[0];; 
        $Row_A = mysql_fetch_array($qatt3); $tabsent = $Row_A[0];; 
        $Row_L = mysql_fetch_array($qatt4); $tleave = $Row_L[0];; 
        $tattp = ($tpresent + $tleave) / $totalatt * 100;
        $Attendance[$index] = round($tattp,0);  
        $index++;
    }
} else {
            $Attendance[1] = 0; 
            $Attendance[2] = 0; 
        }   
$string = array(
x => $Bat_Code,
y => $Attendance[1],
z => $Attendance[2]
 );
 $Str[] = $string;
$i++;
  }
 echo json_encode($Str);
 ?>
```

Issue is that after ajax success function when alert **data** then value show like this

> [{x:'B1',y:14,z:0},{x:'B2',y:27,z:5},{x:'B3',y:38,z:100},{x:'B4',y:77,z:73},{x:'B5',y:71,z:71},{x:'B6',y:0,z:57},{x:'B7',y:0,z:89},{x:'B8',y:71,z:59},{x:'B9',y:0,z:16},{x:'B10',y:5,z:63},{x:'B11',y:0,z:0}]

How to pass morris bar in data? When I giving the `str` variable in morris bar data then morris bar is not showing.

Comment: You should put the Morris-bar code inside the ajax callback. In you current code, the `str` variable won't be set when you're creating the Morris bar since the ajax request is made asynchronously, meaning that the Morris bar will be created before the ajax callback is executed.

Comment: Thanks for supporting.. Can you explain with a code for helpful for me or others?

Comment: Just put the Morris.Bar code inside of the success-callback.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer like this way

```
$.ajax({
dataType: 'JSON',
type: 'POST',
url: "today_attendance.php",
success: function(response)
{
    Morris.Bar({
    element: 'morris-bar',
    data: response,
    xkey: 'x',
    ykeys: ['y', 'z'],
    labels: ['A', 'B']
}); 
 }
});
```